# Calling derived class function from base class function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

In the following code, in the function `set(int, int)` of class `Base`, I want to call the derived class function `showK()`. Is there a way to do this?

I can not declare `showK()` function in class `Base` and i can not make that as virtual. This is a restriction for me.

```
class Base{
    int i, j;
    public:
    void set( int, int );
    void show() { cout << i << " " << j << "\n"; }
};

void Base:: set(int a, int b)
{ 
    i=a; j=b; 
    //Here I want to call the function showk() of class derived . Is there a way to call?.
}

class derived : public base {
    int k;
    public:
    derived(int x) { k=x; }
    virtual void showk() { cout << k << "\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    derived ob(3);
    ob.set(1, 2); // access member of base
    ob.show(); // access member of base
    ob.showk(); // uses member of derived class
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you make `showk` pure virtual?

Comment: Have you come across the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)?

Comment: It is a very bad design. You are expecting the `Base` class to know details about the derived class. So your base will now work by itself or as a base of anything that doesn't have a `showk()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a derived method when the object is not actually of that type could lead to undefined behavior.  I think what you are actually wanting is to have the set() method call showk() if the object is of type derived. It would typically be done like this:

```
class Base{
    int i, j;
    public:
    virtual void set( int, int );
    void show() { cout << i << " " << j << "\n"; }
};

void Base:: set(int a, int b)
{ 
    i=a; j=b; 
}

class derived : public base {
    int k;
    public:
    derived(int x) { k=x; }
    virtual void set(int a,int b);
    virtual void showk() { cout << k << "\n"; }
};

void derived::set(int a,int b)
{
  base::set(a,b);
  showk();
}

int main()
{
    derived ob(3);
    ob.set(1, 2); // access member of base
    ob.show(); // access member of base
    ob.showk(); // uses member of derived class
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem is, the base has no `showk` method, just a `show` one.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I don't see how that is a problem, since it is a method of the derived class that is calling showk().

Comment: My understanding is that OP wants to call `showk()` from `Base::set()`

Comment: @juanchopanza: That is a bit of a nonsensical requirement.  What if the object is not actually of type derived?  I believe the actual intent of the OP was to have the set method call the derived::showk() if the object is of type derived, which is what I implemented.

Comment: It is a nonsensical requirement, but I am not going to try to second-guess OP :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: It is a good point that I didn't explain that I was inferring intent.  I've added some detail in my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

> In the function set(int, int) of class Base, I want to call the derived class function showK(). Is there a way to do this? I can not declare showK() function in class Base and i can not make that as virtual. This is a restriction for me

If you know this is an instance of class derived than you can cast **this** to derived and call the function...

```
void Base:: set(int a, int b)
{ 
    i=a; j=b; 
    ((derived* const) this)->showk();
}
```

You can always do a dynamic_cast instead, to test if it is a derived, if you want to do something different if it's not

(Having said that, I would suggest that if you are in this situation, than something may be wrong with your design.  In general base classes shouldn't "know about" their derived classes.)

Comment: I believe what you show here has undefined behavior, even if `this` has the right dynamic type. You ought to use `static_cast<derived*>(this)` instead. Your code might not work in the presence of multiple inheritance.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: That is not correct. static_cast<T>(x) is exactly equivalent to ((T)x) and to T(x).

Comment: @user1131467: I just checked (§5.4/5), and *in this particular situation*, the C-style cast performs a `static_cast`, so this is safe even in multiple inheritance scenarii. However, if you make a mistake in the C-style cast (`(someotherclass* const) this`), it will behave as `reinterpret_cast` and the compiler will not report the blatant error.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: See current C++ standard, section 5.4 "Explicit type conversion (cast notation)"

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class derived_type>
class Base{
    int i, j;
    public:
    void set( int, int );
    void show() { cout << i << " " << j << "\n"; }
};

template <class derived_type>
void Base<derived_type>:: set(int a, int b)
{ 
    i=a; j=b; 
    static_cast<derived_type*>(this)->showk();
}

class derived : public Base<derived> {
    int k;
    public:
    derived(int x) { k=x; }
    virtual void showk() { cout << k << "\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    derived ob(3);
    ob.set(1, 2); // access member of base
    ob.show(); // access member of base
    ob.showk(); // uses member of derived class
    return 0;
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern